# Javascript - Extract text from a page then build an array with it

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have a table of data that I want to grab text from, stick into an array (and then use with Google maps).

The table looks like:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>One</th>
      <th>Two</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tr class='bar'>
    <td class='name'>Bob</td>
    <td class='number'>12345</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class='bar'>
    <td class='name'>Jane</td>
    <td class='number'>-55.34</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I want to grab the text from the table cells and build an array of it all. Something like:

```
var foo = [
['Bob', 12345],
['Jane', -55.34]
]
```

What I tried, using jquery, was:

```
 var foo = [];
    $('.bar').each(function(){
        foo.push($('.name').text(), $('.number').text());
    });
```

But that, obviously, does not work giving (and I'm pretty sure I'm just using the selector the wrong way):

```
["BobJane", 12345-55.34]
```

So how do you get the contents from each TD within each TR and build the array with it so I get the desired above example (with each set of data in it's own row)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there:

```
var foo = [];
$('.bar').each(function(){
    var self = $(this);

    foo.push([self.children('.name').text(), self.children('.number').text()]);
});
```

You were previously pushing two new values onto the `foo` array. The above code pushes one value (which is an array containing two elements). You also needed to search within the current table row for the correct `name` and `number`, which you can do using [`children`](http://api.jquery.com/children).

If it helps you to understand, the above code can be broken down into:

```
var foo = [];
$('.bar').each(function(){
    var self = $(this);

    var row = [self.children('.name').text(), self.children('.number').text()];

    foo.push(row);
});
```

Comment: "You're almost there"   The story of my programming life.

Answer (score 3):

You could do it [using `.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/) to construct a jQuery object of the values, [and `.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/get/) to pull the Array out of it.

Try this:

```
var array = $('.bar').map(function() {
    var $ch = $(this).children('td');
    return [ [ $.text( [$ch[0]] ), $.text( [$ch[1]] ) ] ];
}).get();
```

Note that when returning an Array inside `.map()`, you need to wrap it in another Array.

Answer (score 1):

Pass `this` as a context to the selectors inside `each` so as to only get **one name/number at a time**. Also make sure to pass an array `[]` to `push` function, instead of two entries.

```
var foo = [];
$('.bar').each(function () {
    var name   = $('.name'  , this).text(); // name from the current .bar
    var number = $('.number', this).text(); // number from the current .bar
    foo.push( [ name, number ] ); // notice []
});
```